# How to run AutoHotkey.exe in the foreground?

Tags: command-line, autohotkey

This command returns before my script is finished:

```
autohotkey myscript.ahk parm1 parm2
```

How do I run this in the foreground (not exit until done)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the command line, where autohotkey.exe is in scope:

```
start /wait autohotkey myscript.ahk parm1 parm2
```